# Raspbian OS run Python3 64-bit

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, 64-bit, raspberry-pi4

can I run 64-bit Python3 on Raspberry Pi 4B with 64-bit Raspbian OS aarch64?

If it is not possible, is installing 64-bit Debian/etc. on RPi4 worth it? For example in performance, ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can.  It is pre-installed.

Comment: I do not have it - I have only 32-bit Python3 on my RPi

Comment: Then it looks like you are running a 32-bit RPiOS or a 64-bit kernel with 32-bit userland.

Comment: It will be probably the problem - I installed RPiOS Lite 32-bit and then in /boot/config.txt I  allowed in section [pi4] arm_64bit=1. Do you know, how can I install 64-bit userland on RPiOS/or at least Python3 64-bit?

Comment: Here is the download link for the 64-bit Lite version:  https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/

Comment: Thank you! In this version it is really pre-installed!